# Redirect nginx internally to https

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, amazon-elb

Not sure if the scenario is possible but this what we want to achive.

Client -> PORT 80 AWS ELB (cannot be changed) -> nginx -> Reverse Proxy -> apache

When /blog is request its proxy passed to https://1.2.3.4

However,  after the reverse proxy happens the url is http and not https.

Based on the architecture above how can we force it to use https  without changing the ELB settings.  (internally going to the https nginx settings)

my nginx config for reverse proxy  is -

```
      proxy_pass https://1.2.3.4/;
      #proxy_pass https://www.example.com/blog;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, 
      OPTIONS';
       proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about how to convert traffic to HTTPS between ELB and Nginx if the ELB's front end listener is HTTP then the answer is - you can't. Because, from security perspective, it doesn't make sense to have this feature. You are sending unencrypted traffic through the insecure Internet and then at the end of the path you want to encrypt it (what would be the point of it, the traffic has already been compromised - or at least you need to assume that it was).

If you really can't change the front end ELB listener, and for whatever reason (most probably not a good one) you need to receive HTTPS traffic on Nginx then your only option is to place another server between ELB and Nginx that will convert the incoming HTTP traffic to HTTPS and pass it to Nginx. But to be honest, this is a terrible solution. You should probably change some other part of your system rather then doing this.

Comment: Maybe i wasnt clear , the ELB listens on port 443 but direct it on 80 internally, the issue is when reverse proxy occur it happens on http

Comment: @JamZ What type of ELB are you using, Classic or Application?

Comment: Classic ELB,  also legacy which  i dont think will be changed as for now

Comment: @JamZ then why don't you just change its back end listener from HTTP to HTTPS. HTTPS -> ELB -> HTTPS is, of course, supported.

Comment: Not sure if there will be other effects from this change, i just need the proxy pass in the specific location to redirect to https, do you have any idea why it uses http? As you can see i am redirecting to https

Comment: @JamZ Is your Nginx server's `listen` set to port 80 in this configuration?

Comment: i have both 80 and 443 listeners

Comment: @JamZ But for the above configuration. Is it used with 80 or 443 listener?